# To get Timestamp from Date and time Android

Tags: android, timestamp

I want to get timestamp from certain date time.
for example, I get these data from date and time picker

```
public static int YEAR = 2021;
public static int MONTH = 2;
public static int DAY = 23;
public static int HOUR = 12;
public static int MINUTE = 56;
```

now how to get timestamp from this datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this following method, give **YEAR**, **MONTH**, **DAY**, **HOUR**, **MINUTE** as input and call it like this

```
Long timestamp = convertToTimeStamp(2021,7,18,23,12) // this method will return 1626630154043 (timestamp)
```

```
    public Long convertToTimeStamp(int YEAR,int MONTH,int DAY,int HOUR,int MINUTE){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,DAY);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,YEAR);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,MONTH-1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,HOUR);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,MINUTE);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `LocalDateTime` object using `java.time.LocalDateTime.of()` method. Also to format have a look at `DateTimeFormatter`.